# Text to fill out circle path constantly

Tags: css, svg

I have a circle path that acts as a text path. I need the text to fill it out consitantly even when the browser window is scaled smaller or larger. A scaling font should make the text line fill the circle path out fully, not less and not more.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="circle">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="15vw" height="15vw" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <path id="criclePath"  d=" M 150, 150 m -120, 0 a 120,120 0 0,1 240,0 a 120,120 0 0,1 -240,0 "/>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
    <g>
        <use xlink:f="#criclePath" fill="none"/>
      <text fill="#000" style="font-size: 2.4em; font-weight:900; letter-spacing:-0.03em; text-align:justify">
          <textPath xlink:href="#criclePath">EDUCATION . INSPIRATION . VACATION . </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gstbopkf/3/)

Comment: I tried fiddling around for a while (hopefully understanding the issue correctly). In Chrome and Opera, if I add `textLength="N"` to the `textPath`, where N is roughly 2πr minus some room for padding, things seem to work. FF will work with a `textLength` attribute on the `text` element (doesn't seem to recognize it on `textPath`), but its value seems to need changing depending on the length and size of the text. And IE didn't seem to respond to either.

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg textLength should work in FF if you put it on the text element rather than the textPath element.

Comment: thee does not seem to be a problem in FF. But there is in Safari.

Comment: It looks (surprisingly) perfect on IE9+ and works pretty well on Chrome.
 The text wraps around consistently. I couldn't find any issue with it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯